# SQLtable to JSON with specific format

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

I have a sql table which needs to be converted into JSON, Basic `SELECT * FROM ##T FOR JSON AUTO;` does not work here because JSON format is specific. The output should look like this:

```
[
      {
        "property": "firstname",
        "value": "Codey"
      },
      {
        "property": "lastname",
        "value": "Huang"
      }].
```

And the another problem is the script needs to be dynamic. It need to work even when a new column will be added to the table.

I found this script on the internet:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetJSON @ObjectName VARCHAR(255), @registries_per_request smallint = null
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID(@ObjectName) IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT Json = '';
            RETURN
        END;

    DECLARE @Top NVARCHAR(20) = CASE WHEN @registries_per_request IS NOT NULL 
                                    THEN 'TOP (' + CAST(@registries_per_request AS NVARCHAR) + ') ' 
                                    ELSE '' 
                                END;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ' + @Top + '* INTO ##T ' + 
                                'FROM ' + @ObjectName;

    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;

    DECLARE @X NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[' + (SELECT * FROM ##T FOR XML PATH('')) + ']';


    SELECT  @X = REPLACE(@X, '<' + Name + '>', 
                    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column_ID) = 1 THEN '{'
                         ELSE '' END + Name + ':'),
            @X = REPLACE(@X, '</' + Name + '>', ','),
            @X = REPLACE(@X, ',{', '}, {'),
            @X = REPLACE(@X, ',]', '}]')
    FROM    sys.columns
    WHERE   [Object_ID] = OBJECT_ID(@ObjectName)
    ORDER BY Column_ID;

    DROP TABLE ##T;

    SELECT  Json = @X;

END
```

But the output of this query is:

```
[{column1:1,column2:row 1}, {column1:2,column2:row 2}, {column1:3,column2:row 3}]
```

which is not in the required format.
I would be glad if someone helped me to handle this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main problem is that you have no grouping field to break records apart. Unless the desired result is one super big structure with 1..N property and value fields, which does not make much sense in the way you structured the question using lastname and firtsname. If your database contains only one person with unbounded properties then the question is legit, else you need to add more context..

Comment: So how would you show multiple rows of data?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying it. So basically i have this simple test table"CREATE TABLE my_t (
    column1 INT,
    column2 VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO my_t  (column1, column2)
VALUES
    (1, 'row 1'),
    (2, 'row 2'),
"
Json format of this table needs to look like this:"
  [
  [{
    "property": "column1",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "property": "column2",
    "value": "row 1"
  },
  [{
    "property": "column1",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "property": "column2",
    "value": "row 2"
  }]
  ]"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temp table here, or XML. You can do the whole thing inside the dynamic SQL.

- First create the full JSON object of a single row, inside an `APPLY`.
- Shred that object using `OPENJSON`.
- Construct another JSON object containing each column's name and value.
- Reaggregate those objects using `STRING_AGG`.
- Aggregate the final result using `STRING_AGG` again, appending `[]` to make it a valid array.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetJSON
  @ObjectName sysname,
  @registries_per_request smallint = null
AS

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName)) IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT Json = '';
    RETURN;
END;

DECLARE @Top NVARCHAR(20) =
  CASE WHEN @registries_per_request IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 'TOP (@registries_per_request) ' 
       ELSE '' 
  END;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT
  Json = ''['' + STRING_AGG(t.Json, '','') + '']''
FROM (
    SELECT ' + @Top + '
      j2.json
    FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName) + ' AS t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT t.*
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ) AS j1(Json)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          Json = STRING_AGG(j3.Json, '','')
        FROM OPENJSON(j1.Json) AS j2
        CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT
            property = j2.[key],
            j2.value
          FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
        ) AS j3(Json)
    ) AS j2(Json)
) t;
'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
  N'@registries_per_request smallint',
  @registries_per_request = @registries_per_request;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0472c6/1)

The final result will contain all rows munged together. I doubt this is what you *really* want, but it fits what you have asked. You should be able to modify this to suit a different requirement.

Note also the use of `sysname` for the table name, and the use of `QUOTENAME` to correctly quote it, and the way to pass in a parameter properly to `sp_executesql`.